# EJB without transaction

Tags: ejb

I am using EJB in order to take advantages of:

1. Concurrent (instead of creating 2 threads, I divided the work into 2
   EJB beans).
2. Pooling (I use stateless EJB a lot and I love the idea that the pool
   contains a specific number of bean). This way, I am not afraid of
   running out of memory. Memory usage is more predictable).
3. Asynchronous processing (all I need is just an annotation).

Well, the problem is I am using it with MongoDB so I don't need any transaction. I can use `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` and `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)` annotations but... it means I must specify it everywhere?

Is there anyway to disable EJB transaction by default?

Comment: Since MongoDB doesn't support JTA transactions, simply don't annotate your EJBs.

Comment: isn't it true that all EJB methods have @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) by default? If I don't specify any annotation then it has @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED), doesn't it? 

For example if you invoke bean.methodCall() and if methodCall() only return "hello, world" String, will the container try to wrap a transaction around it?

Comment: What difference will it make if your database doesn't support transactions?

Comment: Have a look at Java EE 7 Samples on GitHub. This [example](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/extra/nosql/mongo) uses EJB and MongDB.

Comment: well, that example doesn't prove anything. Of course it works but that doesn't answer my question. What I want is disabling EJB transaction so that the EJB container doesn't have to "check" for transaction and manage transaction. That will make the bean lighter. In the link above, the container still try to wrap the method with transaction even though the transaction is useless but it's still there.

Answer (score 9):

In an EJB 3.0 container, annotate your EJB (or EJB method) with:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class YourBean
```

for BEAN management. For CONTAINER management instead:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class YourBean
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value is managed by the container but if you dont specify nothing to do i think you solve your problem.

Or annotate all the Ejb to don´t support transaction

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.NEVER)
public class YourBean
```

Remember that the ejb transactions are executed in a hierarchical way, ie if the first method being invoked does not support methods "children methods" are handled in the same way